# Why use 'reload' method after saving object? (Hartl Rails Tut 6.30)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm working on the exercises for chapter 6 of Hartl's Rails 4 Tutorial.  The first exercise tests to make sure that user email addresses are down-cased correctly:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  .
  .
  .
  describe "email address with mixed case" do
    let(:mixed_case_email) { "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM" }

    it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
      @user.email = mixed_case_email
      @user.save
      expect(@user.reload.email).to eq mixed_case_email.downcase
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

What I don't understand is why the 'reload' method is necessary here.  Once `@user.email` is set to the contents of `mixed_case_email` and **saved**, aren't `@user.reload.email` and `@user.email` the same thing?  I took the reload method out just to try it and it didn't seem to change anything with the test.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes in this case `@user.reload.email` and `@user.email` is the same thing. But it's a good practice to use `@user.reload.email` instead of `@user.email` to check more accurately what is saved in the database. I mean you don't know if you or someone add some code in after_save which changes it's value then it will not have effect on your tests.

**EDIT:**
And also what you are checking is what's saved in the database so `@user.reload.email` more accurately reflects what's saved in database then `@user.email`

Comment: This answer is correct, but not so concise as it could be. Calling reload() is needed if there are post-creation events such as after_create/after_save defined in the tested model. In that case, your in-memory representation will get outdated after the save() method is executed.

Comment: important pedantic nitpick: "exactly reflects what's saved in the database" is only _usually_ true (too many ways it can be untrue to note here). "more accurately reflects... " would be more accurate.

Answer (score 41):

### In-Memory vs. Database

It's important to understand the difference from in-memory and the database. Any ruby code you write is in-memory. For instance, whenever a query is executed, it creates a new in-memory object with the corresponding data from the database.

```
# @student is a in-memory object representing the first row in the Students table.
@student = Student.first
```

### Your example

Here is your example with comments for explanation

```
it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
    # @user is an in-memory ruby object. You set it's email to "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM"
    @user.email = mixed_case_email

    # You persist that objects attributes to the database.
    # The database stores the email as downcase probably due to a database constraint or active record callback.
    @user.save

    # While the database has the downcased email, your in-memory object has not been refreshed with the corresponding values in the database. 
    # In other words, the in-memory object @user still has the email "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM".
    # use reload to refresh @user with the values from the database.
    expect(@user.reload.email).to eq mixed_case_email.downcase
end
```

To see a more thorough explanation see this [post](http://www.derrick-mar.com/rails_blog/under_the_hood_posts/ar_reload).

Answer (score 7):

```
reload
```

Reloads the attributes of object(here @user) from the database. It always ensures object has latest data that is currently stored in database.

With this we can also avoid

```
ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
```

This normally comes when we try to change old version of the object.

Answer (score 6):

It should be the same thing. The whole point is that the reload method reloads the object from the database. Now you can check if your newly created test object is actually saved with the correct/expected attributes.

Answer (score 1):

What the example wants to check is whether the `before_save` callback in `app/models/user.rb` does its job. The `before_save` callback should set every user's email to downcase before it is saved in the database, thus chapter 6 exercise 1 wants to test if its value in the database, that can be retrieved by using method `reload`, is effectively saved as downcase.