# Rails 5 API - has_many through create action is returning 2 records although only 1 is persisted in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have the following M2M through associations for these 3 models

```
Customer -> Residences <- Properties
```

Also Property model is related to Address:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :property
end
```

A customer will always exist before creating a Property.
A property is created by submitting an Address.

Here is the controller action, which works except on success the render always returns 2 properties (ie. basically 2 residence records).

However, only one is in the database. I understand it is related to [stale objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259641/why-use-reload-method-after-saving-object-hartl-rails-tut-6-30), but cannot figure out how to solve it.

I tried adding `@customer.reload` and `@customer.reload.residences` and `@customer.reload.properties` but still get 2 records.

```
  # POST /customers/:id/properties
  def create
    @customer = set_customer
    Customer.transaction do
      address = Address.find_by_place_id(address_params[:place_id]) 
      if address.nil?
        @property = @customer.properties.create
        @property.address = Address.new(address_params)
        if @property.save
          @customer.reload
          render json: @customer, status: :created
        else
          render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      else
        # irrelevant code to the problem
      end
    end
  end

def set_customer
  Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
end
```

A comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297338/how-to-add-records-to-has-many-through-association-in-rails) (from @Swaps) indicates using << instead of create can sometimes result in duplicates, but whichever way I do it I always get 2.

**EDIT**

I managed to force it work like this but this feels like a hack:

```
    if @property.save
      @customer = set_customer
      render json: @customer, status: :created
    else
```

** UPDATE - the models **

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :residences
  has_many :properties, through: :residences
end

class Residence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :property
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address
  has_many :residences
  has_many :customers, through: :residences
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :property
  has_one :location # ignore this, not relevant
end
```

Comment: Are there any validations in the `Property` model? It might be possible that `@property = @customer.properties.create` is actually throwing an error. Can you please change it to `@property = @customer.properties.new` and try again.

Comment: @HalilC Thanks for the suggestion...no validations in Property, Address or Residence models. No error is being thrown. All inserts appear correctly in the logs.

Comment: Also note the entire action is wrapped in a transaction (on purpose) so that if an error was thrown it would be obvious.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So if I understood correctly, before the call the customer object has one property. After success, the customer object in the db still has only one property despite the response includes two properties. Can you check if the old property in the db was replaced with the new one (updated) or the new one is not created in the db at all? You can check the ids for example.

Comment: For this method I am only concerned with creating new properties (hence why the else part is marked irrelevant). So regardless of how many actual properties are in the database, creating a new address (and hence a new property) only ever adds one extra to the database but this code responds with the same new record duplicated. (as if one is coming from cache and one from db - same record with the same ids)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was stale objects in ActiveRecord versus what is in the database after saving.

The ".reload" did not work, I have to actually force ActiveRecord using my hack to force ActiveRecord to find the customer in the database again, and that forces a reload (I presume it invalidates the AR cache):

```
  def create
    @customer = set_customer
    Customer.transaction do
      address = Address.find_by_place_id(address_params[:place_id]) 
      if address.nil?
        @property = @customer.properties.create
        @property.address = Address.new(address_params)
        if @property.save!
          @customer = set_customer # force reload from db
          render json: @customer, status: :created
        end
      else
        address.update!(address_params)
        if @customer.properties.find_by_id(address.property.id).nil?
          # although we updated the address, that is just a side effect of this action
          # the intention is to create an actual residence record for this customer
          @customer.properties << address.property
          @customer = set_customer # force reload from db
          render json: @customer, status: :created
        else
          @customer.errors.add(:customer, 'already has that property address')
          render json: ErrorSerializer.serialize(@customer.errors), status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def set_customer
    Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do manually what ActiveRecord can do automatically with  `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. It even works with `has_many` `through` operations.

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many: :residences, inverse_of :customer
  has_many: :properties, through: :residences

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :residences
end

class Residence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :property

  validates_presence_of :customer
  validates_presence_of :property

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :property
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
  has_many :residences
  has_many :customers, through: :residences

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
end

class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    if customer.save
      redirect_to customer, notice: 'Customer saved!'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(
      name:, ..., 
      residences_attributes: [
        property_attributes: [
          name, ..., 
          address_attributes: [
            street, city, state, postal_code, ...
          ]
        ]
      ]
    )
  end
end
```

References:

- https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes
- https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and links...but you will notice I stated "the customer will always already exist".  The user never submits a customer AND and address/property at the same time. They are separate operations. So accepting nested attributes for customer I think will not solve this problem. But maybe accepting nested attributes for Residence/Property will solve it ...I am not entirely sure...need to read those links.

Comment: Missed that. Thanks for the correction. Hopefully, the idea still helps.

Comment: I will definitely try it when I have time and report back. So thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this?

```
def create
  @customer = set_customer
  Customer.transaction do
    address = Address.find_by_place_id(address_params[:place_id]) 
    if address.nil?
      @customer.properties.new(address_params)
      if @customer.save
        render json: @customer, status: :created
      else
        render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    else
      # irrelevant code to the problem
    end
  end
end
```

I was thinking do you really need @property instance variable. Is it for your view files?

**Update 1**

Could you please add your Customer and Residence model as like this:

Customer model

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :residences
  has_many :properties, through: :residences
end
```

Residence model

```
class Residence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :property
end
```

Comment: lol...you read my mind...I have been wondering if I need that too. It's a Rails api, so the views are just json...and no @property is not needed for rendering that. I will give this a try and see.

Comment: No, this fails because it is trying to create a new address but there is no property (these are a one-to-one relationship, so if I combined them then maybe your code could work). But you are right that "@property" does not need to be an instance variable, can just be "property". But I would still need property.new so that afterwards I can do "@customer.properties << property.address" or .create

Comment: @rmcsharry I have updated my answer. Could you please check this. But if you need property.new anyway you could go for "@customer.properties << property.address"

Comment: Actually I think you done need property.new if you change as Update 1 mentioned

Comment: thanks for continuing to try to help. I added my models, they are the same as your update 1. So I still think the issue is related to what is in memory from ActiveRecord query versus database.